# Getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when I login with Drupal admin

Tags: drupal

Yesterday I have logged in to my Drupal site with admin details and tried to clear the cache data in "Performance" menu. After that I am unable to login to admin it is displaying the below error.

> The example.com page isn’t working
>
> example.com didn’t send any data.
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

If I clear the cache the site is working fine and normal user login is also working fine. But when I am trying with admin it is displaying the above error. I have truncated the cache tables and checked but no use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like WSOD (White Screen of Death), which in Drupal often occurs because of insufficient RAM for PHP.

You could put these commands at the beginning of the `index.php` so you can at least get an error message instead of the blank page:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```